# Add custom Header to raw push notification on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, header, windows-phone, push-notification

`HttpNotification` class that handles raw notifications has `Headers` property. But unfortunately, it's always empty collection and I don't know how to get `X-MessageID` or some other custom header when notification is received

```
static void Channel_HttpNotificationReceived(object sender, HttpNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    string header = e.Notification.Headers["X-CUSTOM-HEADER"];
}
```

Comment: This should be self explanatory: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202977(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: In this article no headers used. They read content from `e.Notification.Body`

Comment: You're right it doesn't accept/handle additional custom Headers